# Inferred type in for each loop is wrong?

Tags: typescript, for-loop, types, syntax

I have a member variable `mine` of type `MyClass[]` and want to iterate over it in some of my functions.

A simple way of iterating would be to use TypeScript's for in syntax, `for(let myClass in this.mine) {}`. The inferred type of `myClass` should therefore simply be `MyClass`.

However, when hovering over `myClass` in VS Code, it informs me that the type of it is supposedly `string`, for no apparent reason. Within the for loop, I also seem to be unable to use member functions of the `MyClass` type.

Could the compiler/linter be thinking that I want to iterate over the keys of my array which could be strings, even if I am, in fact, not using any keys?

What could be causing this issue, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, the correct syntax seems to be `for(let x of arr)` - *of* instead of *in*. Slightly confusing.

Source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

Comment: Yeah, `for-in` loops over an object's keys, which for an array happens to also be its indices. `for-of` will loop through an iterable's actual values.